# Popup window to block only parts of the view hierachy behind it

Tags: android

I have an app that works in the following way:

- Upper part of the screen is the 'primary' part of the app, the actual content that the user can interact with is displayed here.
- Lower part of the screen (maybe 1/4 of the screen height or so) is a navigation wheel. The user can turn this wheel to change the upper part of the display. When turned the entire upper part is replaced by something else.

These two part are implemented using fragments. The lower part (navigation wheel) is just a static fragment that displays a view hierarchy that can be rotated. The upper part (content display area) is a fragment as well, but it can be switched to other fragments when the wheel is turned.

Now what I want is that when the app starts, we are displaying a free content section, however when the user turns the wheel to one of the other content sections a window pops up to block the content display area, saying "buy this mode on Google Play." This popup should obviously block the content area behind it, so the user can see some of the display area behind the popup, but he/she cannot interact with it before he/she has completed the Google Play transaction. It would be nice if the views of the content area could be greyed out as well. The navigation wheel in the bottom of the screen however should not be blocked so that the user is able to navigate back to where he/she came from or further on to another content section. How can I make a popup that blocks the top view hierarchy from interaction but leaves the lower one intact?

As far as I know it is not possible to use [the PopupWindow class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to create a popup that will only block some of the screen behind it. It seems to always block it all.

Here is an of illustration the design. 'P' for paid and 'F' for free. On the second screen the app should ignore any press on the content section (behind the grey window), but the navigation wheel should still be able to turn.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the second screen the app should ignore any press on the content
>   section (behind the grey window), but the navigation wheel should
>   still be able to turn.

You could make an overlay and set it up to eat all touch events(either by setting a `OnTouchListener` on it or by using a custom layout with the `onTouch()` method overriden to return `true`) and put it on top of your normal fragment content. This way the actual content will be visible underneath but will not receive any touch events. You could also add some content to your overlay right like in your image.

Also, as the overlay will only cover the paid fragment the wheel at the bottom will be touchable by the user(I don't know how that wheel actually interacts with your fragments so the approach above might not work).

I've made a small rudimentary sample as an example(you can find it [here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/fragment/PaidFragmentOverlay.java)).

> It would be nice if the views of the content area could be greyed out
>   as well.

You could make a recursive method to traverse the view hierarchy of your paid fragment and call `View.setEnabled(false)` on the views it meets.

Comment: Thanks. This was the kind of answer I was hoping for. I guess I still have a problem though: In your code, the layout called 'content' gets the overlay added to it. My content object is not a FrameLayout but a RelativeLayout. Can I achieve the "overlay effect" with a RelativeLayout? In other words: Is it possible for me to get the "overlay effect" without changing my layout container from RelativeLayout to FrameLayout? It seems to me that RelativeLayout positions its element relative to each other and not on top of each other.

Comment: @AHaahr You can make the overaly with a `Relativelayout`, as you can place child views on top of othe chldviews with either `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`(but even if you have a `LinearLayout` or any other container it's very easy to wrap it in one of the two containers mentioned). In the example I posted there's a small bug, call `disableViews(content);` before adding the overlay, otherwise the overlay and its views will also get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complicated to me.. I cannot imagine the design..

I would create a different fragment to be triggered if the user has purchased the item, with a different interaction, like a Dialog to be shown at every click, or something like that.

In pseudocode:

```
if wheel.position == 4
    if itemPurchased
        showFullFragment
    else
        showMockFragment
```

Comment: This is the way it is working now more og less. The thing I am asking is this: How can I have an app where there is a popup window covering some of the layout but leaving the wheel part active for user input. I have added some illustration to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Create a default fragment with one button, that opens the right page of Google Play to buy the content. Then, every time the navigation wheel is turned, you decide in your code if you show the fragment with content (when user has finished the Google Play transaction) or you show the default fragment with just the button to Google Play.

Only one thing: Google Play is asynchronous. There might be some time when the user actually has finished the transaction but Google Play didn't inform your App, yet.

If the transaction was initiated you must decide if you show the content without having to 100% clarity that the user actually paid, or if you show a blank fragment. In any way, you should not show the button again, because that would confuse the user ("I paid! Why do I need to go to Google Play again???")